# Return entire collection using GET with Python, Flask, and MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, rest, flask

I'm trying to implement a REST interface for a project by using a Python Flask server that is connected to MongoDB. What I would like to do is return some JSON data containing the contents of my collection db.setpoints which I want to be formatted like this:

**Desired format for JSON content retrieved from mongo collection using GET**

```
  {
        Results:
            {'time1': 'TIME1_STR', temp1: 'TEMP1_STR'}
            {'time2': 'TIME2_STR', temp2: 'TEMP2_STR'}
            {'time3': 'TIME3_STR', temp3: 'TEMP3_STR'}
    }`
```

I can get all the setpoints if I iterate through the time and temp objects but I can't return all of them if I use time1, temp1, time2, temp2, etc. So far I have been struggling to get it to return all contents of the collection if they are like this. Any suggestions?

**app.py**

```
 # Initialize MongoDB
    mongo = PyMongo(app)

    # [GET] retrieve list of setpoints
    @app.route('/setpoints', methods=['GET'])
    def get_all_setpoints():
        setpoints = mongo.db.setpoints

        output = []

        # Find all queries in login collection
        for q in setpoints.find():
            output.append({'time' : q['time'], 'temp' : q['temp']})

        return jsonify({'result' : output})
    `
```

Comment: can you place a debugger and see what is the value of 'q' in each variable ?

Comment: I suggested it to check if the problem is reading from the mongodb or formating them to JSON

Comment: @CristianoAraujo Is there a good way to do this? I ran it in debug mode and it doesn't seem to show that information. I tried using pycharm too but I'm having issues running it

Comment: @pkitsos if youre not comfortable with IDE breakpoints and stuff, you can simply put a `print(q)` inside the for loop to see what q is returning.

Comment: @AliYılmaz I tried that but the print function isn't being displayed

Comment: pkitsos, you may use some IDE like @AliYılmaz said. I personally use Pycharm (they have a community edition). You can google 'debug with pycharm', made quick,click left on the line number for creating a breakpoint, right click the file and 'debug', it will stop on the line you marked and show a box with variables values and etc.